# Twin Paradox - different approaches

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, absolute-units, twin-paradox

What was the difference between Langevin's approach to the twin paradox and Max Von Laue's? I don't understand how Langevin tried to use the idea of absolute acceleration to explain the distinction in time difference?

(Also not sure if this is physics or philosophically relevant?)

Comment: I think this is history of science rather than Physics. I also think (and this is of course a purely personal opinion) that if I see another question about the twin paradox I shall **SCREAM** :-)

Comment: Okay :-) can I transfer the question over to a difference area then?

Comment: If you search this site for *twin paradox* you'll find many, many, many questions about it. In SR (not GR) acceleration is indeed absolute. To see why acceleration affects clocks see [Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Gravitation-Physics-Series-Charles-Misner/dp/0716703440/ref=sr_1_1) chapter 6 or look at [John Baez's article](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/rocket.html).

Comment: @JohnRennie I think it's the term "paradox" that's at fault; I wonder if there would be as much interest/confusion if it were called the "twin incident" instead.

Comment: I understand that it is no longer considered a 'paradox' as it is fully explainable by special relativity, however I don't understand how Langevin tried to use absolute acceleration to explain it?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3562

Comment: It is still a "paradox" within SR because while it is "fully explainable in SR" for some methods of calculation, it is NOT for others. The picture is not self-consistent (without GR), hence, a paradox. One can see this trivially by considering that the traveling twin WILL calculate the earth-bound twin to have aged less, if she only uses SR to explain her observations. Only by noting that she is not in an inertial reference frame during acceleration does she either 1) abandon SR because it doesn't apply, or 2) use the principle of equivalence to derive that the earth twin will have aged more.

Comment: @joshphysics, note that I am NOT saying that solutions using SR do not exist. They do. But the "paradox" is in the self-contradiction of there existing other seemingly correct applications of SR in which the twins do not agree.

Comment: @user1247 If you consider the following fact to be part of SR: "the proper time measured by any observer is given by the arc length along his/her path through spacetime," then one can use "only SR" to explain what happens.  I disagree that there is any self-contradiction; if you somehow misapply SR, then I don't think it's fair to call that a contradiction.  It's not clear to me how "seemingly correct" applications of SR are relevant.

Comment: @joshphysics, your example is precisely what I warned against. That is, giving one solution and then calling it a day. The problem is that from the traveling twin's perspective, SR provides multiple equally valid ways of answering the question. The way of answering that I provided is not a misapplication of SR. The twin looks out his telescope and traces the arc length of the earth twin, and determines it is longer than her own. From her perspective, she has been stationary, with acceleration due to rockets used during a passing gravitating object.

Comment: @user1247: you do not need GR to consistently describe the situation. See the references in my comment above for a fully consistent treatment of acceleration in SR. The travelling twin will not calculate the earth-bound twin to have aged less - at least not if they have read Misner, Thorne and Wheeler.

Comment: @John Rennie, again, just because there is *one* way of calculating it within SR that gives the correct answer, doesn't itself represent any evidence against an internal inconsistency. I don't have access to MTW so I don't know exactly what argument you are referring to, although I'm well aware of the "canon" that you don't need GR to solve the twin paradox. I think this canon is wrong, for reasons that I don't think are particularly difficult to understand. I would appreciate it if you could point out specifically what mistake is made by the twin in my above example.

Comment: @John Rennie, the point is that without the equivalence principle the traveling twin has no way of knowing whether she is following a geodesic or not, despite feeling herself accelerate. The acceleration could be because the pilot fired engines and caused a kink in her worldline, or it could be that the engines were fired in coincidence with a passing gravitation body, such that there is no kink in her worldine. Through her telescope she observes the other twin accelerate, and so depending on her interpretation of her own acceleration she can come to different conclusions about her twin.

Comment: Referring people to Baez regarding SR and acceleration, as John Rennie did above, leads to confusion and not understanding. He says there under "accelerating clocks": *"a "momentarily comoving inertial frame" ... that for a brief moment slows to a stop alongside the accelerated clock, so that their relative velocity is momentarily zero.  At that moment they are ticking at the same rate."* In order for this to work this "brief moment" must equal zero time. But in zero time no clock is ticking (and there is no movement, and therefore no velocity) so the whole thing is just a shame for science.